# Posting events to Azure Event Hubs using Policy defined on Event Hub Namespace

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have created an Event Hub Namespace and 2 event hubs. I defined a Shared Access Policy (SAP) on the Event Hub Namespace. However, when I use the connection string defined on the namespace, I am able to send events to only one of the hubs even though I create the client using the correct event hub name

```
function void SendEvent(connectionString, eventHubName){
        await using(var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName)) {
            // Create a batch of events 
            using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();
            
            var payload = GetEventModel(entity, entityName);
            // Add events to the batch. An event is a represented by a collection of bytes and metadata. 
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.ToString())));
            
            // Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
            await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
            
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Event for {entity} sent to Hub {eventHubName}");
    }
}
```

The above code is called for sending events to Hub1 and Hub2. When I use the connection string from the SAP defined on the Namespace, I can only send events to `Hub1` or `Hub2` whichever happens to be called first. I am specifying the `eventHubName` as `Hub1` or `Hub2` as appropriate.

I call the function `SendEvent` in my calling code.

The only way I can send to both hubs is to define SAP on each hub and use that connection string when creating the `EventHubProducer`

Am I missing something or is this by design?

Comment: How do you test for sending events to Hub1 and Hub2? do you mean in the first time you are using the code `await using(var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, Hub1)) {xx}` for sending to Hub1, then in the next step, you copy the same code, just changing Hub1 to Hub2?

Comment: You'd better add the completed code.

Comment: @IvanYang updated code to reflect actual usage

Comment: Would you mind sharing your connection string, with any shared key information redacted?   I'm curious if you're using the Event Hub-level connection string rather than the namespace-level.

Comment: @JesseSquire I double checked the connection string. I can confirm it is not the connection string issue. The Hub level CS does not have the hub name in it.

Comment: Can you help me understand what the error is that you're seeing and at what point in your code?

Comment: @JesseSquire Unfortunately there are not errors or exceptions. I call `SendEvent`. Pass it Hub CS and `Hub1` as the name. Event is sent to Hub1. Then call again sends Hub CS and `Hub2` But that call does not go thru. No errors. 

However, if I call `SendEvent` with Hub1 CS and then with Hub2 CS events are logged as expected. I want to know if the inability to send events to named hubs using Hub CS is by design or if I am missing something.

Comment: If you were having an issue with your token, you would see an exception at the point where you call CreateBatchAsync, as that is when the connection and link are established.   At the end of your SendAsync call, the Event Hubs service has acknowledged the events or would respond with an error for the client to parse.   So long as you're awaiting the call (as your example does) then the service confirms receipt of the events.  We may want to take a look at the consuming end of your process as the potential point of failure.

Comment: @rams, can you solve the issue now?

Comment: @IvanYang not yet. Got pulled into another high priority item. Will get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test at my side, and it can work well at my side.

Please try the code below, and let me know if it does not meet your need:

```
class Program
{
    //the namespace level sas
    private const string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://yyeventhubns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=mysas;SharedAccessKey=xxxx";

    //I try to send data to the following 2 eventhub instances.
    private const string hub1 = "yyeventhub1";
    private const string hub2 = "yyeventhub2";

    static async Task Main()
    {
        SendEvent(connectionString, hub1);
        SendEvent(connectionString, hub2);

        Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void SendEvent(string connectionString, string eventHubName)
    {
        // Create a producer client that you can use to send events to an event hub
        await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName))
        {
            // Create a batch of events 
            using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

            // Add events to the batch. An event is a represented by a collection of bytes and metadata. 
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("First event: "+eventHubName)));
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Second event: "+eventHubName)));
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Third event: "+eventHubName)));
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Fourth event: " + eventHubName)));
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Fifth event: " + eventHubName)));

            // Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
            await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
            Console.WriteLine("A batch of 3 events has been published to: "+ eventHubName);
        }
    }

}
```

After running the code, I can see the data are sent to both of the 2 eventhub instances. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]